# MySql Get sum by date range

Tags: mysql

Here is some table for storing advertising campaign budgets history:

campaign_budgets_history

```
id_campaign  budget date
1            10     2013-01-01
1            15     2013-01-03
1            10     2013-01-05
```

If there are no data for some date, it would be equal to the last set budget.

How can I count the sum of budgets by date range, for example from '2013-01-02' to '2013-01-06'. The result must be $60, because of the budget for '2013-01-02' would be equal to '2013-01-01', and budget for '2013-01-04' would be equal to '2013-01-03'.

Is there are any way to do it via SQL?

Comment: The simplest approach is to construct a calendar table with all possible dates, and then join your table onto that.

Comment: You'd need to follow @Strawberry's suggestion: SUM() is used to aggregate **existing** data so it's necessary to create the missing row data you need for summarisation.

Comment: @Strawberry, even with a table of dates, you still need to find the data row to apply for each date, which means you'll have to determine something like date ranges. ANd once you have such ranges, having the table of all dates becomes prety much superfluous. See my answer for details.

Comment: @MvG Your query's very clever and (I guess) pretty effiecient too. I was simply advocating a simpler approach (see below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a query for you. It uses user variables to denote the ends of the query range, but in the final version you'll likely rather use parameter placeholders instead. Note that `@end` is the first day *after* the range you query, i.e. it's the *exclusive* end of the range.

```
SET @begin = '2013-01-02';
SET @end = '2013-01-07';

SELECT
  SUM(DATEDIFF(IF(CAST(c.end AS date) > CAST(@end AS date),
                  CAST(@end AS date),
                  CAST(c.end AS date)
                 ),
               IF(c.begin < CAST(@begin AS date),
                  CAST(@begin AS date),
                  c.begin
                 )
              ) * c.budget
     ) AS overall_budget
FROM
(SELECT a.id_campaign,
        a.date begin,
        MIN(IFNULL(b.date, CAST(@end AS date))) end,
        a.budget
 FROM campaign_budgets_history a
 LEFT JOIN campaign_budgets_history b
        ON a.id_campaign = b.id_campaign AND a.date < b.date
 WHERE a.date < CAST(@end AS date)
 GROUP BY a.id_campaign, a.date
 HAVING end > CAST(@begin AS date)
) c;
```

Tested on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c622/9). Not sure why all the casts seem necessary, perhaps there is a way to avoid some of them. But the above appears to work, and some versions with less casts did not.

The idea is that the subquery creates a table of *ranges*, each denoting the dates where a given budget was in effect. You might have to adjust the beginning of the first range, to match the beginning of your query range. Then you simply subtract the dates to obtain the number of days for each, and multiply that number by the daily budget.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses a calendar (utility) table...

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE dt BETWEEN '2012-12-27' AND '2013-01-12';
+------------+
| dt         |
+------------+
| 2012-12-27 |
| 2012-12-28 |
| 2012-12-29 |
| 2012-12-30 |
| 2012-12-31 |
| 2013-01-01 |
| 2013-01-02 |
| 2013-01-03 |
| 2013-01-04 |
| 2013-01-05 |
| 2013-01-06 |
| 2013-01-07 |
| 2013-01-08 |
| 2013-01-09 |
| 2013-01-10 |
| 2013-01-11 |
| 2013-01-12 |
+------------+

SELECT SUM(budget) total
  FROM campaign_budgets_history a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(y.date) max_date 
         FROM calendar x 
         JOIN campaign_budgets_history y 
           ON y.date <= x.dt 
        WHERE x.dt BETWEEN '2013-01-02' AND '2013-01-06'
        GROUP
           BY x.dt           
     ) b
    ON b.max_date = a.date;
```